# Field theory questions about polynomials and extension

Tags: field-theory

I have three questions of field theory that I cannot solve and I would like hints to solve them.

> Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a commutative field. Show that the ring $ \mathbb{K}[X]$ contains an infinite number of irreducible monic polynomials.

> Let $P \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ and $Q\in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ be monic polynomials. Show that if $P$ divides $Q$ in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ then $P \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$

> Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a commutative field and $\mathbb{L}$ an extension of $\mathbb{K}$. Show that $\mathbb{L}   $ is an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{K}$ iff every subring $A$ of  $\mathbb{L}   $ that contains  $\mathbb{K}$, is a field.

For the first one, I wanted to try reasoning by contradiction but I don't know how  to write that there is a finite amount of monic irreducible polynomials.

The second one I want to try writing what the condition means and try if it works out.

For the last one though, I have almost no idea since we haven't gotten a lot into field extensions (just basic definition) in my course, so I do not really know.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Why doesn't "Assume there is finite amount of monic irreducible polynomials." work?

Comment: You already know that a subring is closed under addition, subtraction, and multipication.  Only one operation left to go to show it's a field.

Comment: It means that there is a finite amount of monic polynomials $P \in \mathbb{K}[X]$  such that if $P=QR, Q,R \in \mathbb{K}[X]$ $Q$ or $R$ is invertible. But i do not know how to use this.

Comment: Oh i have an idea. Maybe i can consider all the $P_n$ that are irreducible monic polynomials and then construct a new monic polynomial lets say $ S=1_{\mathbb{K}}+P_1P_2 ...P_n $ which is a new monic polynomial which has to be reducible since it is not any of the $(P_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. This means there exists a $T\in \mathbb{K}[X]$ such that it divides $S$. I would want $T$ to divide one of the $(P_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and i would be a contradiction but is it true that if $T$ divises $S$ then it divides one the $(P_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ ?

Comment: I think i can say that :
Suppose $S$ is reducible then there exists $T \in \mathbb{K}[X]$ divides $S$ then it divides $S-P_1P_2...P_n=1$ this is impossible since $1$ has degre 0 and $T$ has at least degree $1$ (its irreducible). So $S$ is irreducible. Is this okay?

Comment: Yes, you got the first one correct. It would be better if you edit this into your question, rather than leave it in the comment. The second one uses the fact that $\Bbb Z$ is a unique factorization domain and hence is integrally closed. For the third one, notice that if $x\in L$ is not algebraic over $K$, then $K[x] \subseteq L$ is isomorphic to the polynomial ring over $K$ and hence not a field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are some standard results that have multiple different approaches.

(1) You can use Euclid's Proof of the Infinitude of Primes (A question: Why doesn't the proof show that any UFD has infinitely many prime ideals?). If $K$ has infinitely many elements, then $\{x-a\mid a\in K\}$ is an infinite family of monic irreducible polynomials. If $K$ is finite and if there are only finitely irreducible polynomials, then $\bar K$ is finite as well, but we cannot have a finite algebraically closed field, by e.g. $x^{p^n}-1$ must have $p^n$ distinct roots in $\bar K$, and $p^n\rightarrow\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, where $p = \text{char}(K)$.

(2) Apply Euclidean algorithm for division to $P, Q$ in $\mathbb Q[x]$, you'll see that the algorithm will never produce a non-integral element (the key here is $Q$ is monic). Or assume $Q=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$ and $R = P/Q = \sum_{i=0}^m b_i x^i\in\mathbb Q[x]$. If $R\not\in \mathbb Z[x]$, then let $k$ be the smallest $i$ such that $b_k\not\in\mathbb Z$, we have the coefficient of $x^k$ in $R$ is $c_k=\sum_{i+j=k}a_ib_j = b_k + \sum_{i\ge 1, \text{ }i+j=k} a_ib_j\in\mathbb Z$, then as $b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_{k-1}\in\mathbb Z$, $b_k = c_k-(a_1b_{k-1} + a_2b_{k-2}+\cdots a_{k-1}b_1)\in\mathbb Z$. A contradiction.

(3) If $L/K$ is algebraic and $K\subset A\subset L$, for any $a\in A$, $a$ satisfies an irreducible polynomial of degree $\ge 1$, say $p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^nc_ix^i = x\sum_{i=1}^n c_ix^{i-1} + c_0$. If $c_0=0$, then $p(x)$ is reducible. Therefore $c_0$ is a unit in $K$, hence $p(a) = a(\sum_{i=0}^n c_i a^i) + c_0 = 0$, $a^{-1} = -c_0^{-1} (\sum_{i=0}^n c_i a^i)\in A$. If $L/K$ is not algebraic, it contains a transcendental element $a\in L\setminus K$, such that $K[a]\cong K[x]$, and we know the polynomial ring $K[x]$ is not a field, hence $L$ contains a subring $A=K[a]\supset K$ that is not a field.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was writing something for the 2nd one that is akin to your 2nd idea.